# awk cartesian product

Tags: perl, awk, normalize

I have large tab-separated two-column text file, like this:

```
...
"001R_FRG3G"    "81941549; 47060116; 49237298"
"002L_FRG3G"    "49237299; 47060117; 81941548"
"002R_IIV3" "106073503; 123808694; 109287880"
...
```

As you see second column doesn't contain atomic values. That's why i want to "normalise" this file to have something like:

```
...
"001R_FRG3G"    "81941549"
"001R_FRG3G"    "47060116"
"001R_FRG3G"    "49237298"
"002L_FRG3G"    "49237299"
"002L_FRG3G"    "47060117"
"002L_FRG3G"    "81941548"
"002R_IIV3" "106073503"
"002R_IIV3" "123808694"
"002R_IIV3" "109287880"
...
```

Anyone knows how to do it effectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl:

```
perl -lne '
s/[";]//g;
($a, @b) = split;
print qq("$a" "$_") for @b;
' FILE
```

Comment: In my case this was the fastest among all provided solutions and one of (only) two actually working...

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {gsub(/[";]/, "", $i); printf "%s%s\"%s\"", $1, OFS, $i; printf "%s", "\n"}}' inputfile
```

For each field after `$1`, strip quotation marks and semicolons, then print `$1` followed by the contents of the field surrounded by quotes. Do this for each line in the input file.

Comment: @mnowotka: The desired output you show in your question includes quotes around each data item. My script strips the quotes and adds them back to give output as requested and as I described in my answer. How exactly does it not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU awk):

```
awk '{while(/;/) $0=gensub(/^((.*[ \t]").*);[ \t]*/,"\\1\"\n\\2",1)};1' file
"001R_FRG3G"    "81941549"
"001R_FRG3G"    "47060116"
"001R_FRG3G"    "49237298"
"002L_FRG3G"    "49237299"
"002L_FRG3G"    "47060117"
"002L_FRG3G"    "81941548"
"002R_IIV3" "106073503"
"002R_IIV3" "123808694"
"002R_IIV3" "109287880"
```

or, it's not awk but it elegantly solves the problem.

```
sed -i ':a;s/\(\(.*\s"\).*\);\s*/\1"\n\2/;ta' file
"001R_FRG3G"    "81941549"
"001R_FRG3G"    "47060116"
"001R_FRG3G"    "49237298"
"002L_FRG3G"    "49237299"
"002L_FRG3G"    "47060117"
"002L_FRG3G"    "81941548"
"002R_IIV3" "106073503"
"002R_IIV3" "123808694"
"002R_IIV3" "109287880"
```